# Slang definitions of ハゲ

Tags: words

> 私に命令するな。何様だこのハゲ。
>
> Don't tell me what to do! Who the fuck does this idiot think he is?

Besides meaning bald, or a bald/balding person, when cursing, does ハゲ also just become a generic curse word such as "douchebag" or "asshole"? In this sense, does it stay mostly male-restricted? What would be the nuances of this usage of ハゲ (ie perhaps still implying an older man?)

My 21 year old friend said this:
日本ではたとえ禿げてなくても「ハゲ」と罵ることが多々あります。

Answer (score 4):

I think [ハゲ](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%AF%E3%81%92/UTF-8/) is often similar to the English words [baldy/baldie](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/baldie):

> 私に命令するな。何様だこのハゲ。
>   Don't order me around! Who the hell does this baldie think he is?

In the absence of other sources, I'll refer to this [Kotonoha page](http://kotonoha.cc/no/215376) for whether it can be used for non-bald people:

> ハゲの人には言わないよ。ハゲてないからこそ言えるんだ!
>   You don't say it to people who are bald. They aren't bald so you can say it!
>
> ...
>
> 「ハゲてねぇし!」と返ってくる
>   The response is "I'm not bald!"

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad word, but is still only used in its literal sense. It is not used against a person who is not actually bald. It is different from words like `asshole`, which is used against a person who is neither an `ass` or an `asshole`. The word has no gender or age restriction, but is perhaps used more against male and/or the aged because of the reality.

Comment: yes, it can be used against non bald people.

Comment: At least in fiction, I have encountered one case of a character using ハゲ against non-bald people -- 猿柿{さるがき}ひよ里{り} from Bleach (it's her 口癖). No other characters question this speech quirk other than ツッコミ responses (ハゲてへんわ！). If there's nothing more to the word, then I guess I have to blame the writing quality -- surely, calling random people "baldy" would normally elicit a response of "What are you talking about??" rather than a ツッコミ. But if the OP's character is in fact not bald (and the speaker isn't Hiyori), then two instances of this pattern seem to point to something else going on.

Comment: So it means something like "geezer"? How about エロハゲ. Is that just エロ + ハゲ? Sleazy creep? Perv? Or something like that? I am looking for definitions of エロハゲ.